How do I handle audio files in React using Vite?
I am trying to create a simple react app that uses wavesurfer.js to just play and visualize an audio file.
I am using Vite + Typescript + SWC and of course React.
Here is my attempt to doing this :
import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import WaveSurfer from 'wavesurfer.js';

function App() {
  const waveformRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);
  const wavesurfer = useRef<WaveSurfer | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (waveformRef.current) {
      wavesurfer.current = WaveSurfer.create({
        container: waveformRef.current,
        waveColor: 'rgb(200, 0, 200)',
        progressColor: 'rgb(100, 0, 100)'
      });

      wavesurfer.current.load('./assets/original_ekt.mp3');

      wavesurfer.current.on('ready', () => {
        console.log("WaveSurfer is ready!");
      });

      return () => wavesurfer.current?.destroy();
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <div ref={waveformRef} style={{ width: '100%', border: '1px solid black' }}>
      </div>
      <button onClick={() => wavesurfer.current?.playPause()}>
        Play/Pause
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

However I am getting erros when trying to play the audio :

Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The media resource indicated by
the src attribute or assigned media provider object was not suitable.

I suspect it has something to do with CORS but I am not sure.
How do I manage ressources in this kind of environement ?

Update : I was not putting the audio file in the /public folder, ence the error.
